# how to set textbox value to empty(blank) using javascript in facebook

Tags: javascript

I want to set my textboxes empty(blank) once user posted or skipped feed box in facebook. i m using following code:

```
var attachment = {
         .........some code here............
 };
Facebook.streamPublish('', attachment,actionLinks,null,null,clear);

}

function clear()
{
 document.getElementById("question").setTextValue() = "";
}
```

but this is not working.
please help me.....

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming the element you want to change has the id `question`, so you can do

```
document.getElementById("question").value = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JavaScript Code : 

document.getElementById("question").value = "Your value goes here";

Jquery Code :

if it's a simple text
$("#question").text("Your text goes here");

if it's a HTML code
$("#question").html("Your HTML goes here");

if you want to append to the current text value
$("#question").append("Your text goes here");
```